# what is the difference between loadClass(("fully qualified class name") and <ClassName>.class.getDeclaredConstructors

Tags: java, data-structures, java-stream, classloader

```
class testMe{

    void show(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}

public class ClassloadersExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ClassLoader c = ClassloadersExample.class.getClassLoader(); //Line 1
        try {
            Class c1 = c.loadClass("test.testMe"); // Line 2
            Constructor a[] = c1.getDeclaredConstructors(); 
            for (Constructor constructor : a) {
                testMe m = (testMe)constructor.newInstance();
                m.show();
            }

            Constructor con[] = testMe.class.getDeclaredConstructors(); // Line 6
            for (Constructor constructor : con) {
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                testMe t = (testMe)constructor.newInstance();
                t.show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

    }
}
```

I am testing above code. Both give me the same result. I am trying to understand the difference between line 1,2 and line 6. I can achieve the same result by both the approaches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919494/class-fornamename-newinstance-vs-name-class-newinstance-difference-in-us

Comment: Check if `c1` and `testMe.class` is the same thing.

Comment: If you already have java class then you could do `testMe.class.getDeclaredConstructors()` but if you have only string name of a class like `"a.b.c.d.MyClass"` for example from config file then you first need to "convert" it to java object of type `Class` with `Class c1 = c.loadClass("a.b.c.d.MyClass")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

There is no *functional* difference. As you have discovered, there are various ways to get a `Class` object and to instantiate instances of that class. They all lead to the same result, however.

In general, until needed otherwise, always:

- Use class literals or `getClass()` for obtaining a `Class`

  - Example 1: `Class<Foo> cl = Foo.class;`
  - Example 2: `Class<? extends Foo> cl = fooInstance.getClass();`
- Use the `new` keyword for instantiating instances

  - Example: `Foo f = new Foo();`
  - *Caveat: Sometimes the API is designed using the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), etc... If this is the case then you'll have to use those methods. Internally, the builders and factory methods might even use the `new` keyword.*

---

## Explanations and Minor(?) Differences

#### Classes

Off the top of my head, these are the ways I can think of to get a `Class` object:

1. Using [class literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)

   - `Class<Foo> cl = Foo.class;`
2. Calling [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) on an instance

   - `Class<? extends Foo> cl = fooInstance.getClass();`
3. Calling [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

   - `Class<?> cl = Class.forName("some.package.Foo");`
   - This is shorthand for `Class.forName("some.package.Foo", true, currentClassLoader)`
4. Calling [`ClassLoader.loadClass(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String))

   - `Class<?> cl = classLoader.loadClass("some.package.Foo");`
   - Won't necessarily *load* the `Class`. If the `Class` has already been loaded then that loaded instance will be returned.

All the above will get the `Class` object that represents `some.package.Foo`. In all likelihood (I'm not *100%* certain), methods 1, 2, and 3 all end up delegating to method 4 eventually.

You'll notice that the generic signatures of the `Class` objects (the `<>` parts) are different depending on the way you get the `Class`. Methods 1 and 2 know what type the `Class` will be at compile-time and so can return a `Class` with the appropriate generics. Whereas methods 3 and 4 have no idea what type the `Class` will represent at runtime and therefore return a `Class<?>` (`?` is a wildcard).

Something to note about method 3. As I mentioned above, `Class.forName(String)` is shorthand for `Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader)` where the `boolean` will be `true` and the `ClassLoader` will be the current `ClassLoader`. The `boolean` parameter determines whether or not the `Class` is initialized. To initialize a class means (among other things?) initializing all the `static` variables and running the `static` initializers. So while methods 1, 2, and 4 will **not** initialize the `Class`, method 3 **will**. If you don't want method 3 to initialize the `Class` you'll need to use the longer version and make the `boolean` parameter `false`.

The link in the question comments talk about why you would use methods 3 or 4.

#### Creating Instances

Once again off the top of my head, these are the ways I can think of to instantiate objects:

1. Using the `new` keyword

   - `Foo f = new Foo();`
2. [Using `Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())

   - `Foo f = fooClass.newInstance();`
   - Requires that the class has a no-arg constructor
   - *Deprecated since Java 9 in favor of using `Constructor` objects*
3. Using one of the [`Constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) objects

   - `Foo f = fooClass.getConstructor().newInstance();`

The major difference here is *how* each method creates an instance. The first method simply uses the `new` keyword. The 2nd and 3rd methods use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful). Reflection is useful when you don't know the types at compile-time but should be avoided until needed.

Method 3 uses `Class.getConstructor(Class<?>... paramterTypes)`. Since I'm passing an empty array of parameter types the returned `Constructor` is a no-arg constructor. This would fail if the class does not have a no-arg constructor.

Your use of `getDeclaredConstructors()` simply returns *all* the constructors and then you pick the one you want and call `newInstance`. The example I gave in 3 bypasses this by going straight for the public no-arg constructor. Using `getDeclaredConstructors()` will also give you the *non-public* constructors (i.e. `protected`, `package`, and `private`). This can allow you to call a non-public constructor you wouldn't otherwise be able to. But this is only if you have the available access to call the constructor; you'll need things like permission from any installed `SecurityManager` and (if using Java 9+) the package that the class is in must be reflectively-accessible (`opens`) to your module.

#### Some Links

- [object created with “new” keyword and created with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103693/object-created-with-new-keyword-and-created-with-reflection)
- [Difference betweeen Loading a class using ClassLoader and Class.forName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285855/difference-betweeen-loading-a-class-using-classloader-and-class-forname)

  - [Class.forName() vs ClassLoader.loadClass() - which to use for dynamic loading? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100376/class-forname-vs-classloader-loadclass-which-to-use-for-dynamic-loading)
- [Class.forname(“name”).newInstance() vs name.class.newInstance : Difference in usage perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919494/class-fornamename-newinstance-vs-name-class-newinstance-difference-in-us)

Comment: So the short answer to the question is that writing "test.testme.class" has the same end result as calling loadClass("test.testme"). It's just two different ways to get the classloader to load a class and return to you a Class object representing that class.